# SQL Query with two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm new to SQL queries, so I have some problems making them. I'm using SQL Server Management Studio.

My task is to select regional groups of departments where average of salary + commission of employees is less than 2500.

My SQL statement:

```
select regional_group 
from LOCATION 
join DEPARTMENT on location.location_id = DEPARTMENT.location_id 
join EMPLOYEE on DEPARTMENT.department_id = EMPLOYEE.department_id 
where EMPLOYEE.department_id in (select avg(salary + commission) 
                                 from employee)
```

[Structure of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3BPr.png)
[image]

Comment: can you put some dummy data to show us what you want as an output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to put condition in where clause of inner query

```
select regional_group 
from LOCATION 
join DEPARTMENT on location.location_id = DEPARTMENT.location_id 
join EMPLOYEE on DEPARTMENT.department_id = EMPLOYEE.department_id 
where EMPLOYEE.department_id in (select department_id 
                                 from employee 
                                 where salary + commission < 2500)
```

Comment: `where avg(salary+commission) < 2500` can you please add avg function to your answer. In question, he/she asked for average of salary and commission.

Comment: @Kas why you want average of salary. can you explain it. I am not sure you want average of salary and commission

Comment: It's written in my exercise at university. I don't know why they need the average:D

Answer (score 0):

SQL Query

```
Select L.Reginal_group
From Employee E
Join Department D ON
D.Department_id = E.Department_id
Join Location L ON
D.Location_id = L.Location_id
WHERE avg(E.salary+E.commission) < 2500
```